# xampp phpmyadmin fatal error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, windows-10

Trying to access phpmyadmin through xampp and Windows 10, been working for months without a problem, now after trying to load for a looooong time i get a fatal error message!!!

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 286

[image: Screenshot of error]

I need this to be working, tried updating phpmyadmin to the latest version to no avail!!!

HEEEEELP!!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by changing the value for the param max_execution_time in php.ini:

```
max_execution_time = 360      ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds (I CHANGED THIS VALUE)
max_input_time = 120          ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
;max_input_nesting_level = 64 ; Maximum input variable nesting level
memory_limit = 128M           ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB by default)
```